# Rich Internet Application

Tags: ajax, rich-internet-application

I need to create an engaging, rich application (administration panel for a school). Management of the schools students, classes, teachers and so on.

I search for something more advanced than simply using jQuery/Flex/Silverlight. Advanced means not so low-level, something I can grasp an application quickly.

I want to put my application together quick - as I would do with plain HTML. 
But HTML (without AJAX...) is not advanced (not rich) enough for applications.

so I need a framework which can be used to create rich applications fast and easy.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your main criterion is how quickly you can put it together, your best option is going to be to stick with something you know, or something related to something you know. Your language of choice probably has some sort of framework available for RIA. Perhaps giving us some idea of the languages/frameworks you're most familiar with will help us recommend something.

Comment: So... it needs to be "more advanced" than jQuery/Flex/Silverlight, but "fast and easy" and "quick". And a full framework which is "advanced". Looks like you'll need to invent it yourself. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You want it to be quick, fast, easy, but without any complicated coding. Sounds like you need to hire a developer...

Comment: I do not agree. Complicated coding should be used for complicated projects, not for the most common project on the internet -> admin-panels and business applications

Answer (score 1):

Try ExtJS javascript framework. It's designed  for rich applications, has tons of rich UI controls and the final app looks more like desktop one.

You can connect these controls to JSON API on the server, so it can be easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight and Jquery is ridiculously high level and easy, there is no doubt that you will not find anything with that balance of abstraction/productivity and create-ability.

Comment: Good answer, but may be I can make some compromises in the "create-ability" if there is a tool focused on online business applications and admin-panels.

Comment: Silverlight has some built-in business application templates/frameworks that already have admin-panel type functionality, waiting for you to add your controls and content.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a very good match for [Vexi](http://vexi.sourceforge.net/) (disclaimer: I'm a Vexi developer).

The main benefit of Vexi is that layout is really easy, as it is a box model.  It's easier to understand than HTML even.

```
<box>
    <box orient="vertical">        .-------------------.
        <box fill="red" />         |   red   |         |
        <box fill="blue" />        |---------|  green  |
    </box>                         |   blue  |         |
    <box fill="green" />           '-------------------'
</box>
```

Scripting is done with JavaScript, and there's an extensible widget set.  Using widgets is easy too.

```
<button id="button1" text="My button" />
<textarea id="text1" shadowtext="Type in here!" />
```

The applications are rich, desktop-like and are user interfaces that are "projected" over the Internet - all the application logic resides on the server which you create in your language of choice and expose via an XmlRpc interface.